# How to use pagination along with laravel eloquent find method in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, pagination, laravel-5.4

I am trying to implement pagination in laravel and got following error

```
Undefined property: Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator::$name
```

Here is my controller function

```
public function showTags($id)
{
    $tag = Tag::find($id)->paginate(5);

    // when lazy loading
    $tag->load(['posts' => function ($q) {
        $q->orderBy('id', 'desc');
    }]);

    return view('blog.showtags')->withTag($tag);
}
```

Here is the Tag Model

```
class Tag extends Model
{
    public function posts() 
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Post');
    }
}
```

The Tag and Post model has belongsToMany Relationship so there are many posts under the specific tag and my aim is to iterate all posts under the specific tags descending order of post and also to implement pagination in that page.

Here is the code for showtags view

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Tags</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php $count = 1; ?>
    @foreach($tag->posts as $post)
        <tr>
            <th>{{ $count++ }}</th>
            <th>{{ $post->title }}</th>
            <th>@foreach($post->tags as $tag)
                    <span class="label label-default">{{ $tag->name }}</span>
                @endforeach
            </th>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>

//Here is the code i used for pagination in view
<div class="text-center">
    {!! $tag->posts->links() !!}
</div>
```

If anybody know how to do this please respond. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure if I'm missing something but `find` only gets a single row, so you can't paginate that. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @apokryfos I know that find only give one row but you can see in my view that I iterate every posts under the same tag since tag has belongs to many relation with posts. My aim is to organise all posts under the same tag by pagination. So is there any way to do that

Comment: So you'd probably do something like `$tag->posts()->paginate(5)` or something like that.

Comment: In the function `showTags($id)` the `$id` is a tag ID. Right?

Comment: @apokryfos thanks for your suggestion i replacing $tag->posts->links() with  $tag->posts()->paginate(5) in my view and   removes error from the view and slight modification of controller accordingly help me to solve the problem .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solve the problem by using a simple trick. My aim was to paginate all posts under the same tags just like you guys can see in StackOverflow.

The modified controller function is

```
public function showTags($id)
{
    $tag = Tag::find($id);
    
    // when lazy loading
    $tag->load(['posts' => function ($q) {
        $q->orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(10);
    }]);
    
    return view('blog.showtags')->withTag($tag);
}
```

As you guys see that I move the paginate() function from find to load function which I use before for sorting post by descending order.

Now in view instead of using traditional method `{!! $tag->links() !!}` for making link of pagination

I use `{!! $tag->paginate(10) !!}`

Answer (score 0):

With this line `$tag = Tag::find($id)->paginate(5);` You should get only one tag(or null if tag with your id  dose not exist), and after that you want paginate it. If you want paginate your tags get all tags and after that paginate it `Tag::paginate(5)`