# Laravel pagination how appends long string

Tags: laravel, pagination

I just started learning laravel. There was a problem, I make a selection from the database of 5000 records with pagination.

My data looks like this
380673113513
380673113514
380673113515
380673113516 ... 
and a few thousand more

I break them into an array

```
$numberList = explode("\r\n", $request['inputList']);
```

And I make a selection with pagination

```
$objects = Number::has('object')->with('object')->whereIn('number', $numberList)->Paginate(1000);
```

To work pagination, I retransmit the data of my form

```
{{ $objects->appends(['inputList' => $_REQUEST['inputList']])->links() }}
```

As a result I have such links 
http://telbase.dev/list?inputList=380673113513%0D%0A380673113514%0D%0A380673113515%0D%0A380673113516%0D%0A380673113517%0D%0A380673113518%0D%0A380673113519%0D%0A380673113520%0D%0A380673113521%0D%0A380673113522%0D%0A380673113523%0D%0A380673113524%0D%0A380673113525%0D%0A380673113526%0D%0A380673113527%0D%0A380673113528%0D%0A380673113529%0D%0A380673113530%0D%0.................&page=2

If there is a lot of data, the string is very long and the server returns an error 414 Request URI Too Large. I think that I initially do something wrong. How to correctly pass such a large request in pagination.

ps Sorry for my English, i am use google translate)

Comment: why do you transmit the data in the url? I cant really understand what you trying to do, but for pagination you just need the PAGE parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

web.php:

```
Route::post('/'data, '<controllername>@<functionname>');
```

controller:

```
public function <functionname>(){
    //logic to create data
    $data = response()->json([
        'data' => $data
    ])
    return View::make('<view_name>', array('data' => $data));
}
```

then you should be able to access it in your view:

```
{{$data[0]-><attribute>}}
```

or do a foreach statement...

Comment: I'm doing similar stuff in the current app I'm building with a few thousand records without any problem.

Comment: But how paginate this data

Comment: See if anything here helps. https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42293157/how-to-use-pagination-along-with-laravel-eloquent-find-method-in-laravel-5-4&ved=0ahUKEwj3g_-hjr3UAhVELmMKHcX-DKgQFgghMAI&usg=AFQjCNGejT6T7mBPh5eTIjWOE29WlgTIXA&sig2=Bdbwr5j-mRPNZvzDyWiuvw

Answer (score 0):

Are you using POST method? If not you should because the length of a get request is limited where a post to the server configuration.

Comment: I get data from textarea using post. But as I understand, to work pagination, I need to re-transmit them to the url

Comment: I would think that you would make a view with the data. like return Route::post('/'data, '<controllername>@<functionname>')

Answer (score 0):

web.php

```
    Route::get('/test', [
    'uses' => 'TestController@test',
    'as'=> 'test'
]);

Route::post('/test', [
    'uses' => 'TestController@test',
    'as'=> 'test'
]);
```

controller

```
public function test(Request $request)
{
        $numberList = explode("\r\n", $request['inputList']);
        $objects = Number::has('object')->with('object')->whereIn('number', $numberList)->Paginate(10);
        return view('objects.test')->with('objects', $objects);
}
```

view

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="{{ route('test') }}" method="POST">
   <textarea class="form-control" name="inputList" id="inputList"></textarea>
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">go</button>
   <input type="text" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}" hidden>
</form>

        @if ($objects->count() > 0)
            @foreach( $objects as $object)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ $object->number }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $object->object->fio }}</td>
                </tr>
            @endforeach
            {{ $objects->links() }}
        @endif
```

When I make a request in the form, the result is displayed normally.
But when I try to go to page 2, I get an empty page with the form.
All because when you go to page 2 $ request ['inputList'] is already empty, and as a result $ objects is also empty.
Why is that?